# Apply callbacks on nested objects

Tags: php, symfony

I have the following serializer on Symfony 5.0, it has some callbacks to handle some of the properties. I'm looking for a way to apply the `$decimalCallback` on the `object->products->value`, but I can't how it can be done,

```
<?php
//src/Serializer/OrderSerializer.php

namespace App\Serializer;

use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ObjectNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\AbstractObjectNormalizer;

/**
 * 
 */
class OrderSerializer
{
    public function serialize($orders)
    {
        $encoder = new JsonEncoder();

        $maxDepthHandler = function ($innerObject, $outerObject, string $attributeName, string $format = null, array $context = []) {
            return $innerObject->id;
        };
        $dateCallback = function ($innerObject, $outerObject, string $attributeName, string $format = null, array $context = []) {
            return $innerObject instanceof \DateTime ? $innerObject->format('Y-m-d H:i:sP') : '';
        };

        $decimalCallback = function ($innerObject, $outerObject, string $attributeName, string $format = null, array $context = []) {
            return is_int($innerObject) ? $innerObject/100 : '';
        };

        $defaultContext = [
            AbstractNormalizer::CIRCULAR_REFERENCE_HANDLER => function ($object, $format, $context) {
                return $object->getId();
            },
            AbstractNormalizer::CALLBACKS => [
                'createdAt' => $dateCallback,
                'updatedAt' => $dateCallback,
                'deliveryDate' => $dateCallback,
                'shippingCost' => $decimalCallback,
                'productsValue' => $decimalCallback,
                'totalValue' => $decimalCallback,
            ],
            AbstractObjectNormalizer::MAX_DEPTH_HANDLER => $maxDepthHandler,
        ];

        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer(null, new CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter(), null, null, null, null, $defaultContext);

        $serializer = new Serializer([$normalizer], [$encoder]);

        return $serializer->serialize($orders, 'json', [AbstractNormalizer::ATTRIBUTES => [
            'id',
            'shippingCost',
            'productsValue',
            'totalValue',
            'status',
            'createdAt',
            'updatedAt',
            'deliveryDate',
            'groupId',
            'receiverName',
            'user' => [
                'id',
                'username',
                'name',
                'customerInfos',
            ],
            'products' => [
                'id',
                'vtexId',
                'quantity',
                'value',
                'description',
                'referenceId',
                'createdAt',
                'updatedAt'
            ],
            'productAccessories' =>  [
                'id',
                'vtexId',
                'quantity',
                'value',
                'description',
                'referenceId',
                'createdAt',
                'updatedAt',
            ],
            'addresses' => [
                'id',
                'type',
                'postalCode',
                'street',
                'neighborhood',
                'number',
                'complement',
                'city',
                'state',
                'country',
                'createdAt',
                'updatedAt',
                'product' => ['vtexId'],
                'productAccessory' => ['vtexId'],
            ],
            'transaction' => [
                'id',
                'transaction',
                'fingerprint',
                'event',
                'oldStatus',
                'desiredStatus',
                'currentStatus',
                'createdAt',
                'updatedAt',
            ]
        ]]);
    }
}
```

On the `$defaultContext` declaration I already tried:

```
AbstractNormalizer::CALLBACKS => [
    'createdAt' => $dateCallback,
    'updatedAt' => $dateCallback,
    'deliveryDate' => $dateCallback,
    'shippingCost' => $decimalCallback,
    'productsValue' => $decimalCallback,
    'totalValue' => $decimalCallback,
    'products' => ['value' => $decimalCallback]
],
```

But it didn't work, the only thing that worked was changing it to `'value' => $decimalCallback` but it changes all instances of `value` witch can't happen.

On my research I came across the `Symfony\Component\Serializer\Annotation\SerializedName` compoment but it need to work together with `Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\MetadataAwareNameConverter` and I can't see how to make it work also using the `Symfony\Component\Serializer\NameConverter\CamelCaseToSnakeCaseNameConverter`.

Comment: Not sure, if this will work for you, but would it work for you if you apply it to `value` and then do a check in your callback if it's a decimal value instead of something else?

Comment: I did something like this for the time being, instead of returning empty on the callback when it's not a integer, I just return the old value instead of the decimal and applied to all "value" fields.